# Issue With Rotation On Character Rig

Tags: animation, rigging, transforms, transform-orientation

I am having issues when trying to rotate the root bone of my character rig around the z axis.

When pressing r, then z, I am able to rotate the rig perfectly normal, but when I play the animation back, the root rotates along the y axis.

When I look in the transform tab, it also displays a change in the y axis even though I am rotating the z axis.

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

**Using Global rotation where you want local rotation**

[image]
Global and local rotation of default bone about z axis.

<kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> is rotate around global z axis. eg Default bone of default single bone armature points up. The y axis of a bone is its head to tail. Rotating this bone around global z axis rolls the bone around Y.

Instead to rotate bones around their local axes use

<kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've tried rotating around the local axis but am still having issues. I'll send a gif if I can figure out how.

Comment: I think I am having an issue with axis locking. When I rotate local z in the transform tab, the y rotates. When I rotate y the y rotates as well. And when I rotate x it rotates x as normal. The z axis seems to be locked causing issues.

Comment: If one of the components of rotation is a multiple of ninety degrees, yes you maybe seeing gimbal lock. Recommend editing some kind of illustration into question.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, I just had a similar issue using quaternion as a rotation mode in my armature, honestly, I ignore what the rotation modes are and what each of those does(Which I definitely need to learn), but I changed the rotation mode to XYZ Euler (since I heard Qaternion was a bit hard to work with) and fixed my problem.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for replying! Unfortunately I was already using XYZ Euler :( I've tried other ones but they all mess rotations incompletely. Again, thanks for the input :)